# Requested format of data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, which looks like this.

```
test_id        time_utc               sim_mcc_mnc   network_name
 1234    '2015-01-14 14:03:56'         '232-10'          A1
```

There is only 20 types of "sim_mcc_mnc" and I have to get number of samples (records) for each month. It is not difficult to get it in this format:

```
sim_mcc_mnc    year    Month      Number of records
   232-10      2013   January          1234
   232-10      2013   February         4321
```

But I was requested (From person who knows the same as me about MySQL -- also beginner) to do it this way.

```
sim_mcc_mnc   January    February  March  ....
   232-10      1234        4321    5678    (these numbers are number of records)
```

I think it is completely against the "philosophy" of MySQL and it is probably imposible to do (unreasonable difficult).

My question is:

1. Your point of view on it.
2. Is it possible to get the data in requested format?

Thank you for every opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done like this *

```
select sim_mcc_mnc, 
       sum(case when Month(time_utc) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Jan,
       sum(case when Month(time_utc) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Feb,
       ...
from your_table
group by sim_mcc_mnc
```

And you can use it if you need a report in this format for instance. Nothing really wrong about it.

<sub>* BTW that query does not take the year into account. That part is unclear in your example.</sub>

Specifically in MySQL this can be done a little shorter

```
select sim_mcc_mnc, 
       sum(Month(time_utc) = 1) as Jan,
       sum(Month(time_utc) = 2) as Feb,
       ...
from your_table
group by sim_mcc_mnc
```